# Authentication failure when pushing code to repository directly

Tags: git, github

Colned a repository in `https` mode and directly opened(i.e. without fork) in git desktop app by `"Open in Desktop"`.

Made some changes and committed it.

When I'm pushing the code I am getting below error:

```
Authentication failed. You may not have permission to access the repository or the 
repository may have been archived. Open options and verify that you're signed in 
with an account that has permission to access this repository.
```

I am able to push via fork and create pull request.
I am new to Github. Is it because I can't directly work on this repo and I need to fork and then push on it and then create pull request?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because I can't directly work on this repo and I need to fork and then push on it and then create pull request?

Yes, it sounds like this is the case. I assume you're not a member of the original repo, so you won't have write access to it.

The normal way to contribute to a github project (that you aren't a member of) is to create a fork in your account (so its url is `Ukita/CoolProject` instead of `OtherGuy/CoolProject`), clone that, make your changes, push to your fork, then create a pull request in the original project pointing back to your fork.

If you're comfortable working with git remotes, you could still use your clone from the original, but you'll have to manually add your github-hosted fork as a remote and push to that. I'm not sure how (or even if) you'd do that via the github desktop app though, I've never used it.

It's definitely a little confusing at first, but not too complicated once you get the hang of it.